How to print CMYK-PDF from Linux to HP CP5225 without any color management?
I've created a CMYK (Pre-Press, PDF/X-1a) PDF using Scribus on (Mint) Linux. When I print this PDF from a PDF viewer to my HP Laserjet CP5225, the output looks terrible. Text (which is black in the PDF) seems to be printed with color. It looks unsharp. I guess that some color management is being done.
Is there a way to print a CMYK PDF on the HP printer directly, i.e. bypassing any manupulation by some printer driver. (Not sure, if my HP would be able to print PDF directly).
Edit 1
I have printed the PDF from a Windows machine to the very same HP printer, and the output looks good. So it definitely is a problem of printing from Linux, not problem with the PDF. In Windows, there are two printers is defined: One as PCL, one as PS printer. Both outputs look good.

You using postscript for output?

The vast majority of home and office printers do not support CMYK files.  Convert it to RGB first. Then try again.  CMYK images are intended for print processes which use separations, such as lithography or screen printing. It's not a requirement for digital printing.

@BillyKerr this one has postcript support so it defnitely supports cmyk

@joojaa No, I'm using the PDF exported from Scribus. Exporting as EPS only puts single page into the output file. From Windows, I have the option to use the printer as either PCL or PS printer (two printers installed). I cannot find an option to select "PS" under Linux.

@phunsoft - If this is an issue with the Linux print driver,  it's not really something we can help resolve here since hardware and operating system specific questions are generally off-topic.  Have you tried asking about this on  Unix & Linux Stack Exchange?  In the meantime, since you don't appear to have support for CMYK, just make an RGB version of the PDF.

@BillyKerr - Yes, I understand this is not the place to ask OS specific questions. My main question still ermaind unanswered: Is there a way (irrespective of the OS) to print directly to the HP printer?

I suppose you could try using a PDF reader to print the file.  This usually works in Windows using Adobe Reader, but on Linux I have no idea if this would be a viable solution.

You can't, in general, "bypass a print driver".  The driver is what sends data to the printer. If color is an issue, you can probably disable color management on the printer itself through it's menus and options.

It should do cmyk right if you use the postscript output. But ofcourse you have no calibration. Nor do we know that your pdf is correct. Is it possible for you to share a simpified pdf to verify your colors are correct, and not just rich black and yes all bets are off when printing with random pdf viewers like the default browser one.
